# How to set a gem binary in path?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a gem I have built with an executable.  The executable is under the `bin` directory of my repo and it is defined in the gemspec file:

```
  spec.executables   << 'my_gem'
```

After installing the gem the executable is also installed correctly:

```
$ ls /Users/myuser/.gems/gems/my_gem-1.0.0/
bin/ lib/
$ ls /Users/myuser/.gems/gems/my_gem-1.0.0/bin/
my_gem*
```

However I want to add this executable in the path so I can run something along the lines of `my_gem` or `bundle exec my_gem` to run the executable from the cli.

What do I need to add to my gemspec file to do this?

Here is my ruby version and ruby gems versions:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76
$ gem -v
2.2.2
```

Here is my gem env:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.1 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 76) [x86_64-darwin15.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/myuser/.gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/myuser/.gems/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/myuser/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/myuser/.gems
     - /Users/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
     - /Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["https://rubygems.org/", "https://my.org.url/artifactory/api/gems/gem-public/"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
     - https://my.org.url/artifactory/api/gems/gem-public/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/libexec
     - /Users/myuser/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/myuser/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

The weird thing is that I already attempted this with a different gem I created using the [gem tutorial](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable) and that works just fine.

**Update:** When debugging this for some reason it's running the `lib/my_gem.rb` file instead of the `bin/my_gem` file.

Comment: You don’t need to add anything to your `gemspec`, this should work already. How have you installed Ruby? If this isn”t working then you likely haven’t got the gem bin directory on your `$PATH`. The results of `$ gem env` would be useful too.

Comment: I don’t know rbenv, but I _think_ you might need to run `$rbenv rehash` after installing the gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem has been installed properly.  The issue is actually with the executable.

The executable I created ended with this common if statement:

```
if $PROGRAM_NAME == __FILE__
  main
end
```

To fix it I just had to change it to this:

```
main
```